# Why can't our self-replicating message in a bottle stay in Sol?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, apocalypse

Suppose we knew of an extinction level event in a few decades, and through a large Manhattan Project-type effort humanity manages to construct a [von Neumann probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_spacecraft) with a copy of all human knowledge.  Like with Voyager's record but more sophisticated.  A self-replicating message in a bottle from a dying civilization.

Are there any plausible disasters that would provide the reason why such a probe should be sent to a different star system first instead of starting in our own system on, say, Mars or the asteroid belt or just hibernating on Earth for a few millennia?

Since everyone is (or will be soon) dead, time isn't really a factor, but the energy to get a spacecraft at solar escape velocity certainly is.

Bonus points the further you'd have to send the probe.

Comment: The sun turning into a red giant would require the probe leaving but since that's not going to happen for ages I don't think it's that useful for your story.

Comment: @Bellerophon - yeah, the billions of years from now issue is mildly problematic.  I could make it an alien civilization ala the TNG episode "inner light", but I'd prefer it to be Earth.

Comment: The whole point of a 'message in a bottle' is to be discovered.

Assuming we don't have any intelligent alien life forms on our solar system (let's say Europans can exist, but intelligent to the level of Octupus at best), why delay the journey at all?

Comment: @Sach I'm assuming we don't know of any particular aliens, as then we'd just send a regular probe or even just beam a message to them.

I'm not sure what you mean by delay?

Answer (score 4):

## The Solar System will soon be englobed

I'm basing this off my current story in progress, for which I've asked a [supporting question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/141298/aliens-englobed-the-solar-system-will-we-notice) here on SE:WB. My idea (not really my idea, the core element is about as old as antiquity) is that early on in our development, astronomers find tantalizing evidence of an astronomical structure surrounding the Solar System, and then, much, much later on, it is discovered that the structure is a barrier prohibiting us from leaving.

Perhaps in your story, humanity learns of a similar barrier soon to be thrown up; perhaps a message or visitation from the barrier creators warns us of it, for whatever reason they'd choose to do that.

Comment: Getting a strong Deathworlders vibe going on here...

Comment: @JoeBloggs I haven't heard of it before, but now that I have it looks like a good read. I'm guessing somewhere in the chapters, a biiigg barrier is erected?

Comment: Many big barriers. Also a Von-Neumann probe swarm. But mostly just humans being ridiculously overpowered by normal interstellar standards.

Answer (score 4):

Through sheer luck, a planet-hunting satellite has detected micro-lensing events that are eventually deduced to be due to a primordial black hole (one that masses less than our Sun).  The hole is quiescent at discovery, because it's been in the low-density interstellar medium for millennia, but it's soon discovered that a) its heading relative to the galactic background is constant, and b) its distance (detected by additional lensing events) is reducing.

Anyone familiar with navigation knows that "constant bearing, closing range" is a more precise way of saying "collision course."

A tiny black hole passing through the Solar System would be disastrous, but not an immediate extinction event -- disrupting the orbits of the planets wouldn't kill everyone quickly, though there's reason to believe it would do so over a period of centuries (you think *we* have a climate change problem).  However, every refinement of the measurements continues to indicate collision course -- in fact, if not a direct hit collision with the Sun, a miss so close that the black hole will draw gas from the Sun as it passes.

The *very best* possible outcome is a series of flares that will each sterilize the face of the Earth then in day, down to a depth of multiple meters in water and a few tens of centimeters in soil.  There's enough error to believe there's also a possibility of a black hole induced supernova explosion (if the hole center-punches the Sun); such an event would melt the day side surfaces of the inner planets, sweep off their atmospheres -- well, further details are counter productive.

The good news is, we have a bit more than a century before the hole arrives.  The bad news is that our message in a bottle needs to be well beyond the Kuiper Belt by that time, to be sure a supernova doesn't disrupt its systems enough to effectively destroy it.

Comment: The Sun erupting as a supernova is a dubious proposition. Great flaring seems much more realistic.

Comment: @BMFForMonica Sol is too small to supernova -- but there are new hypotheses that suggest too-small stars may supernova if they swallow a black hole.  One less massive than the sun still might not do it, I'm not an astrophysicist by any stretch.

Comment: I'm not an astrophysicist either, but here's what I think I know: For the PBH to enter the Sun (at realistically tens of km/s) and *remain* inside the Sun, it would have to interact with at least its own mass' worth of solar innards, imparting that needed opposing momentum. A PBH's cross-section would be small, because, well, they're supposed to be tiny. I think it is unlikely to encounter that much material on a journey through the Sun.

Comment: Furthermore, upsetting the Sun's hydrostatic equilibrium, lending to any sort of explosion, would likely take considerable, *astronomical* time. That PBH's small cross-section doesn't do it any favors. It could take it billions to trillions of years to build up to any considerable size. As it grows larger, so does its accretion disk, which would lend to radiation pressure preventing further material from falling into it, stunting its own growth.

Comment: As previously noted, I'm not an astrophysicist.  I do recall, however, that if the hole has an event horizon even as big as a tennis ball it'll evaporate slowly enough to last a long time, and in in a high pressure gas/plasma environment, ought to collect matter pretty quickly.  Also, the effect of gravity causing a density increase in the Sun's outer layers should be effectively immediate.

Comment: I just doubt that the PBH would encounter enough solar material on its way through the Sun to do any real damage to it.

Comment: @BMFForMonica As I understand it, it's the gravity, rather than cross section, that matters for the black hole induced supernova.

Comment: https://www.universetoday.com/12837/what-would-happen-if-a-small-black-hole-hit-the-earth/ this seems to suggest a PBH at the smaller end of the spectrum would barely even register as a blip if it hit the Earth, let alone the sun.  However https://www.universetoday.com/1930/are-microscopic-black-holes-buzzing-inside-the-earth/ suggests a PBH stuck inside a star could cause a premature nova.  But I get the impression "premature" here means a bit sooner, not like, even a century.  So neat idea but I'm not sure a PBH will do it.  A stellar remnant might, but then I think we'd see it right now.

Comment: @JayLemmon Thanks for the links.  A stellar remnant black hole can't mass less than the Sun (minimum to form from a supernova is about 1.4 Solar masses, as I recall, that or a bit more to form from accretion on a neutron star), but would otherwise fit above.  Wouldn't get a supernova if it center punched the Sun, but it'd be a life-ending event anyway.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - A stellar black hole would have to be massive, yeah, but it could be a small neutron star.  From https://medium.com/starts-with-a-bang/ask-ethan-79-the-tiniest-neutron-star-e5808e8fa328 they can be about as small as Saturn mass-wise.  But I'm not sure how stealthy it would be (obviously there are pulsars on one end of the spectrum but I'm not sure how quiet a neutron star could be.  At the very least there'd be blackbody radiation).  There are also more exotic things like strangelets or strange stars but that's getting pretty far fetched.

Comment: I think, in the end, the gravitational disruption of a big enough PBH passing through a star would likely be enough, and long-lasting enough, to wipe out all life inside the orbit of Saturn or further.  Or at least could be hand-waved to be.

Answer (score 1):

**The probe is small, Earth is at risk**.  We are talking about current Earth.  We don't have technology to move people off of Earth in any appreciable way at the moment, and we certainly couldn't sustain a colony on another planet if Earth is uninhabited.  You'd need a suitably big asteroid to ensure total extinction of humanity, but such an asteroid wouldn't be **that** big.  Maybe a rogue planet that we couldn't detect until it was too late (since it's so dark) whips into the solar system on a collision course.  No one is surviving that **and there is such a huge debris field that nothing is safe anywhere in the vicinity of Sol**.

So, you only have the technology and resources to reliably launch a small-ish probe, replicating or not, and not any appreciable subset of humanity.

Comment: Depending on what the "extinction-level event" prompting the von Neumann machine is, it may not matter that Earth is at risk from it.

Comment: @BMFForMonica: Perhaps, but the question isn't why wouldn't we send people but why doesn't the probe start replicating in the Sol system.  We need a plausible event to make the solar system itself a bad choice of location to store the probe for a while

Comment: This reminds me of a sort of Kessler syndrome but on the scale of a whole system.  I'm somewhat sceptical we wouldn't be better off sending the probe to, say, one of the moons of Uranus or Neptune, though.  Space is a big place and I'm not sure even an Earth sized shrapnel bomb is going to make the entire solar system inhospitable to our probe.

Answer (score 1):

Does being wipedout by genocidal aliens count as a disaster?

Because that would be a good reason to send it far from home. Probably the most plausible reason to need to send it as far away from home as possible, and fast.

Comment: The problem is it would have to be a very slow genocide, since I think even conservatively it would take humanity a few decades to build a self replicating probe.